# How to display a uploaded image path in my input (laravel)

Tags: html, laravel, forms, image, uploading

When the user wants to edit its own post, I want the current uploaded image to show up in the input field.
I have tried to pass the path of the image from the database to the value of the input. 
But somehow it does not showing up.

```
<input type="file" name="image" value="{{ $posts->image_path }}>
```

I have checked which data this pass to the view and it is correct.
In the image below you see the path dumped to the page, but I want it in the input field, so if the post changed I don't have to upload the same image again.

[image]

Comment: You can do this using session or ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show the image directly in the Input file (this is not supported).
You can, however, display it directly next to it in an `img` tag

Comment: Okay, strange is this because of security reasons?

Comment: So I need to make uploading an image optional or make a different form for uploading a image.

Comment: @SebastianTramper, yes, optional upload is the best.